# switch case doesn't works

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

my problem is I want to scroll to a specified div **(#morg, #vorm, #nachm, #abe)** and it always goes to the default statement.

Why that?

```
function scrollToCarret(listview) {
var hour = new Date();
var hours = hour.getHours();

console.log(listview + hours);
switch(hours) {
    case hours < "8":
        console.log("< 8");
      break;
    case hours < "13":
        console.log("< 13");
      break;
    case hours < "18":
        console.log("< 18");
      break;
    case hours < "24":
        console.log("< 24");
      break;
    default:
        console.log("faiL");
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What does hours equal when it hits the switch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`switch`/`case` in JavaScript doesn't work like that. It always tests for equality with each of the `case`s.

What it does is converting the conditions (`hours < "18"`, etc.) to booleans because it requires a scalar value for each `case`. Then the value of `hours` is compared to each of the values in the `case`s. Since no matching one can be found (because they're `true` and `false`) it jumps to `default`.

Basically what is run is the following:

```
if (hours == (hours < "8") {
  ...
} else if (hours == (hours < "13") {
  ...
} else if (hours == (hours < "18") {
  ...
} else if (hours == (hours < "24") {
  ...
}
```

Each `case` is compared against the expression you gave in `switch`, in this case that's `hours`.

Yes, I really miss VB's `Select Case` sometimes too. But C-like languages usually have nothing like it (PowerShell does, though ;-)).

Answer (score 1):

[Switch statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) aren't used for anything other than equality with the selector.

In your code, the selectors are the *result* of each of your logical expressions. The following lines are identical, if we assume that hours = 8:

```
case hours < 8:
case (hours < "8"):
case (8 < "8"):
case false:
```

Comment: Please don't refer to w3fools

Answer (score 0):

The `switch` statement works by comparing the first expression (the one following the `switch` keyword) to those following the `case` keywords.

Therefore, in your code your are basically comparing `hours` (expected to be an integer)  to `hours < "8"` (a boolean), which can produce unexpected results.

What you want to do is change :

```
switch (hours) {
    case hours < "8":
        ...
    case hours < "13":
        ...
    case hours < "18":
        ...
    case hours < "24":
        ...
    default:
        ...
}
```

To:

```
if (hours < 8) {
    ...
} else if (hours < 13) {
    ...
} else if (hours < 18) {
    ...
} else if (hours < 24) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```